# Trying to make a template test in XCTest

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xctest

I'm writing automated tests for my company's website and I'm also now writing tests for the iOS app. In my Jasmine tests in javascript I use a `.forEach()` loop to create a test template, for example:

```
[one, two].forEach(function(number){
    it('should print ' + number, function() {
        console.log(number);
    }
});
// Output:
// 'should print one' #=> one
// 'should print two' #=> two
```

Is there any way to do this with Swift in `XCTest`'s?

Answer (score 0):

Swift has for-in loops:

```
let inputs = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
for input in inputs {
    // do something
    print(input)
    // assert something
    XCTAssertTrue(someFunc(input))
}
```

Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Comment: Thanks. I know that these loops are possible, my question was more about putting the actual test function into the loop, since I'd rather stick to one assertion per test.

Comment: You can just replace the print function and assertion with your test code using the input from the array of inputs. Sorry I accidentally wrote output instead of input at one point - I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`XCTContext. runActivity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctcontext) for this and for each item in your loop create a new activity, so your test method can look like:

```swift
func testActivity() throws {
    let numbers = ["one", "two", "three"]
    for number in numbers {
        XCTContext.runActivity(named: "should print \(number)") { activity in
            print(number)
        }
    }
}
```

This is a much more preferred approach than just running assertions with for loop as in your test report you will be able to visualize which iteration from the loop failed/passed:

[image: Activity test report]